# Why Am I Getting This : MySQL Error #2002 (Access Denied) With MAMP?

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I recently tried to access my MySQL database, but for some reason I get the error message "#2002 - Connection refused — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)."

This is really strange, since yesterday it was working perfectably fine, I don't know what I did wrong.

I have MAMP installed on my mac, and the MySQL server is activated.

What do I do to fix this?

Comment: does /tmp/mysql.lock (or something similary named) exist? I remember my days on crappy os x and mamp and having to symlink the mysql.lock every time I wanted to use mysql

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs where do I find /tmp/mysql.lock?

Comment: It might not be called mysql.lock but it'll end in .lock if memory serves me right. If it doesn't exist there then that's the issue and you need to symlink the one in your mysql directory, wherever it may be

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs but where do I write /tmp/mysql.lock ?

Comment: to /tmp/ - if /tmp/mysql.lock doesn't exist you need to create it from your mysql folder. As said in previous comment

Comment: ok it's fixed now, tanks

Comment: No worries :) glad to see you got it working :D